# Is it possible for Australian company to hire a full-time freelancer overseas?

Tags: payment-terms, working-from-home

I'm a working holiday maker in Sydney. Now I'm working for a startup company as a fullstack developer. My working holiday visa is expiring in Feb. The young company now still need some time to become available to sponsor me. During this period, we wonder by law whether it will be possible that I can work for them remotely from overseas?

If yes, what regulation applies? Will this become a contract job, or I have to become a freelancer? How can the company pay me? Do I need to pay tax for Australia?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal immigration question, not a freelance question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's **possible**, but you wouldn't be the company's employee. You can't be an employee because you don't have tax file number for the Australian Taxation. You are welcome to work as an external Chinese contractor, charging your services and pay your own tax in China.